# How to programatically change an item in the options menu?

Tags: java, android, options-menu

When the user clicks on the Menu button I present a few menu items. One of them is a Sign Out button. I want to be able to change the text between "Sign In" and "Sign Out" depending on a boolean value I am tracking. How can I programmatically change the text in the menu?

Comment: in "onCreateOptionsMenu" method do "this._menu = menu;" in ur own method do "MenuItem item = _menu .findItem(1); item.setTitle("test");"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to override the onPrepareOptionsMenu function in the Activity. There is a menu parameter passed, you can simply find the menuitem that you want to show/hide (or change the image and text) and return true.

[onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29)

Comment: Perfect--so much better than changing the item during onOptionsItemSelected()!

Answer (score 3):

Override/Implement the `onPrepareOptionsMenu(...)` callback. Change what you add based on your sign-in state.

Alternatively, I haven't tested this but in my mind it works: When you create your menu items, keep a handle to the Sign In/Sign Out item in a class variable, and just update it by calling `setTitle(...)` as needed.