# android - change options menu dynamically , but by inflating from XML

Tags: android, xml, resources, dynamically-generated, android-optionsmenu

i need to be able to change the options menu (the one that is shown upon pressing the menu button) on android , so that on one case (for example upon a button being pressed) , it will use a specific menu resource (XML file as in /res/menu/... ) for the menu , and on another case , use a different XML file.

so far i've seen only examples of doing it without xml (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876109/how-to-programatically-change-an-item-in-the-options-menu) and [here](http://russenreaktor.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/solved-android-dynamically-change-options-menu-items/)) , and they worked fine , but i want to be able to change the entire menu on some cases.
i've tried to modify the solutions i've found , but none of my trials worked.

if possible , i would prefer to re-create the menu only if the it needs to be updated with a menu resource that is different from the current one.

please help me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to change the Options Menu any time after it's first created, you must override the onPrepareOptionsMenu() method.

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {    
    menu.clear();    
    if (CASE_1 == 0) {
        CASE_1  = 1; 
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.secondmenu, menu);
    }
    else {
        CASE_1  = 0;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.firstmenu, menu);
    }    
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

where CASE_1 refer to the which menu you want to display depending on your requirement.

Comment: won't it mean that it will be re-created each time you show the menu , as opposed to onCreateOptionsMenu ?

Comment: yeah it will be recreated  and you stated it( i would prefer to re-create the menu)

Comment: Or you can have single xml and setVisiblity of each menu itenm to true or false as required. refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030268/set-visibility-in-menu-programatically-android

Comment: is it possible to avoid re-creating the menu each time the end user is showing it? does it even matter much

Comment: you got my vote . thanks. if you know of a way to avoid re-creation of the menu, please tell me.